# Hidden folder in Robocopy

Tags: windows, command-line, robocopy

I'm trying to backup a hard drive with two partitions on it to another drive with only one partition using Robocopy. I am running my commands in PowerShell.

The source drive is a USB2.0 drive and the other drive is a USB3.0.
My volumes are as listed:

- Wolverine  F:\    NTFS      is my destination drive
- Oriskany   G:\    FAT32    one of the two source drives
- Essex        H:\    NTFS      second of the two source drives

I'm using the commands

```
robocopy H:\ F:\Essex\    /MIR /E
robocopy G:\ F:\Oriskany\ /MIR /E
```

I ran the "Oriskany" command first and had no problem;
all data showed up -- about 17GB worth.
The problem occurs when I try to run the command for Essex (213GB). Even if I create the folder before running the command, the folder Essex disappears during running. The data is still there but the only way to get to the folder is to type in "F:\Essex" to open the folder. I checked if it was hidden and it isn't a hidden object so I have no clue what it is.

So what am I doing wrong? I am rather new to command line.

Answer (score 0):

So after digging and digging and channeling my very best google'fu I've come up with an answer to my own problem. Apparently Robocopy had made the directory **System Attribute** for what ever reason. To fix this I found the command.

> attrib -h -s -a [Drive:][Path]

I also adjusted so the target drive was the focus, not sure if that was part of making the command work or not. The command I ended up using to fix my issue is as fallows.

> F:>attrib -h -s -a "F:\Essex"

I'd credit the person I got the answer off of but I'm not sure how SuperUser feels about linking to external sites so I'll just say thank you Ricky.